# JavaScript sum table value

Tags: javascript, html

I have the HTML table below. How can I sum up all of the columns based on continent group?

```html
<html>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Continent</th>
    <th>Population</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <center>Total</center>
    </td>
    <td>
      <center>sum(continent)???</center>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <center>Asia</center>
    </td>
    <td>
      <center>sum(nation)??</center>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <font style="float:right;">IND</font>
    </td>
    <td>
      <font style="float:right;">900,000</font>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <font style="float:right;">JPY</font>
    </td>
    <td>
      <font style="float:right;">25,000</font>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <font style="float:right;">CHN</font>
    </td>
    <td>
      <font style="float:right;">9,000</font>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <center>Europe</center>
    </td>
    <td>
      <center>sum(nation)??</center>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <font style="float:right;">RUS</font>
    </td>
    <td>
      <font style="float:right;">3,000</font>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <font style="float:right;">ITA</font>
    </td>
    <td>
      <font style="float:right;">5,000</font>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <center>Others</center>
    </td>
    <td>
      <center>sum(nation)??</center>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <font style="float:right;">OTH</font>
    </td>
    <td>
      <font style="float:right;">90,000</font>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

</html>
```

Example: in order to get the **Total**, I need to add all of the continents, in this case **Asia + Europe + Others**, but first I need to have the subtotal of those continents. Additional info: Those continents and nations can be editable(add/remove) based on database. How can I do that?

In simple terms, like using Microsoft Excel, where we can sum up each/any column that we want.

I know JavaScript `sum()` that I got from other sites, but so far it only gives me the total for all column values. Below is the code, where **index** equals to number of column.

```
function sumColumn(index) {
    var total = 0;
    $("td:nth-child(" + index + ")").each(function() {
        total += parseFloat($(this).text(), 10) || 0;
    });

    return total.toFixed(2);
}
```

Comment: What Javascript `sum()` function?

Comment: Robby: my bad, forgot to add the code. question edited.

Comment: Is the HTML above static or is being created by JavaScript or a server side platform such as .net or PHP? How are you sourcing your original data? As there's no form input fields how are the values updated?

Comment: Hi Ben, As I've mention the data will be return by PHP from a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to learn on how to use Jquery Selectors, I've modified the snippet according to what you have mentioned. However, what you are trying to do here is a bad way of handling data. You should never represent data in this form. Use PHP or ajax to load data to the elements.

```js
$(function() {
  let asia_sum = 0;
  $('.asia').each( function() {asia_sum+= parseInt($(this).text()); });
  
  let eur_sum = 0;
  $('.eur').each( function() {eur_sum+= parseInt($(this).text()); });
  
  let other_sum = 0;
  $('.other').each( function() {other_sum+= parseInt($(this).text()); });
  
  let total = asia_sum + eur_sum + other_sum;
  
  $('#total').text(total);
  $('#eur').text(eur_sum);
  $('#asia').text(asia_sum);
  $('#other').text(other_sum);
  console.log(other_sum);
  
 });
```

```html
<html>
<head><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script></head>
<body>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Continent</th>
    <th>Population</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <center>Total</center>
    </td>
    <td>
      <center id='total'>sum(continent)???</center>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <center >Asia</center>
    </td>
    <td>
      <center id='asia'>sum(nation)??</center>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <font style="float:right;" >IND</font>
    </td>
    <td>
      <font style="float:right;" class='asia'>900000</font>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <font style="float:right;">JPY</font>
    </td>
    <td>
      <font style="float:right;" class='asia'>25000</font>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <font style="float:right;" >CHN</font>
    </td>
    <td>
      <font style="float:right;" class='asia'>9000</font>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <center>Europe</center>
    </td>
    <td>
      <center id='eur'>sum(nation)??</center>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <font style="float:right;" >RUS</font>
    </td>
    <td>
      <font style="float:right;" class='eur'>3000</font>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <font style="float:right;">ITA</font>
    </td>
    <td>
      <font style="float:right;" class='eur'>5000</font>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <center>Others</center>
    </td>
    <td>
      <center id='other'>sum(nation)??</center>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <font style="float:right;" >OTH</font>
    </td>
    <td>
      <font style="float:right;" class='other'>90000</font>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```